# Get related data from pointer

Tags: java, android, pointers, parse-platform

I have simple data structure:
"Issue" has *poiter* to other class "Status" in field "status"
From doc we know *include* - take *key* name and pointed data should be avalible in result without any action. But then I try to access pointed data I get *null*.

```
ParseQuery<Issue> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Issues");
query.include("status");
query.whereEqualTo("owner", user);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Issue>() {
    public void done(List<Issue> issueList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved " + issueList.size() + " issues");
                ParseObject status = issueList.get(0).getParseObject("status"); //NULL!

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Manualy form console I can see valid data and jump from Issue to Status by pointer (I have only one record in both)

Parse lib version - 1.11
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to get ...can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I need one field from related issue status. F.e status.geBoolean("isActive")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work.. Check your security and ACL settings in Parse Status class (if you don't have the rights to get the status you won't get it), make sure issueList.get(0) is not null and make sure that the Status object you are pointing to really exist in Parse Status table.

Comment: Yes! The problem was in ACL. Use have no permisson to read this data, Thanks!